# why imagepng in foreach loop, create blank images?store only the last one

Tags: php, image, loops, foreach

i try with for loop,while loop, recursion...
nothing help.
maybe some pointers or memory-limit problems?
please help me :(
my code:

```
/*$arrImg = [['name'=>'some name', 'note'=> 'some url-image from ajax'], 
['name'=>'some other name', 'note'=> 'some other url-image from 
ajax']],...];*/
function saveMyImageFromString($string, $filename) {
    $data = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $string)));
    imagealphablending($data, false);
    imagesavealpha($data, true);
    imagepng($data, $filename);

    imagedestroy($data);
    unset($data);
}

$directory = 'img/';
$filename = 'deleteme.png';
$len = count($arrImg);
$iterationHeight = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    saveMyImageFromString($arrImg[$i]['note'], $directory . $i . $filename);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `imagedestroy()` and `unset()` right before the end of the function. When the function returns, all its variables are unset.

Comment: You should probably check if `$data` is `false`, meaning that the image could not be created

Comment: @Barmar true for `unset` but it's a good idea to clean up image resources with `imagedestroy`

Comment: Is the problem really with the loop? What happens if you just call your function on one item, without the loop?

Comment: with only one, work perfect.if i have more...only the last image is created ok,the others images are blank.i will try unset only(like Phil told me :) )

Comment: it`s still the same problem...blanck images,only the last one is ok

Comment: @Barmar if i have img1 img 2 and img 3, the content of img3 is stored in img 1.the rest is blank.maybe is some php reference loop issue...

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the contents of `$arrImg`.

Comment: @Barman you are my hero.the problem was in one event-listener in my js.i put .off() from jQuery and everything work now.thanks for your advice :)